# React-Native init multiple projects possible?

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I am able to

- create `AwesomeProject`
- start the server
- make changes
- reload js without any issues.

My problem starts when I try to create a new `React-Native` project.

I run `react-native init AnotherProject` and it created the new `react-native` project under `AnotherProject` folder.

Under `cd AnotherProject` when I try to start `react-native run-android`, I get the following error:

> Command failed at checkExecSynchError (child_process.js:441:13)

However, it works fine when I run the same command under the `AwesomeProject` folder.

Is there something I am missing here?
Or only 1 react-native project can be run on 1 Windows PC?

Any ideas why this happens is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the issue might be with your packager.  Check to make sure you are running `react-native start` in the directory of `AnotherProject` and not in the directory of `AwesomeProject`.